# Camera pretrigger capture

Tags: camera, python-3

Hi i want to make a program that will continually record a video and on a press of a button, it will save 2 minutes before i pressed the button is it possible to do it somehow ?

Comment: To capture a video 2 minutes before you perform an action, wouldn't that require a time machine or mind reader device or both? If you are considering that the device record constantly and capture only the two minutes prior to the button press, it may be advisable to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Both the third-party Python picamera API and the official raspivid command-line program support this. picamera calls it ["circular stream"](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#circular-record1) and the flag for raspivid is  `-circular` .

You really should study the excellent picamera documentation in-depth since it discusses easy and complex applications of circular buffers. One wonders how people not using Python cope, seeing that their Raspberry camera libraries are almost abysmal in comparison.

Comment: The python code references in their documentation can be found here: [Circular Buffer](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/recipes2.html#splitting-to-from-a-circular-stream) and 
[Basic Circular Buffer](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/recipes1.html#circular-record1)

Comment: Updated reference for things like this: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html?highlight=circular%20buffer#recording-to-a-circular-stream